# How can i declare two dimensional array of buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In C#, how can i declare a two dimension array of buttons?

Comment: Why do you have two different questions?

Comment: `Button[,]` is a 2d array of buttons

Comment: -1: It's really not cool to remove the question you have answers for, leaving the other one left.

Comment: how can i allocate position of them in form?

Comment: @VishnuTS You have to understand, that Stackoverflow is **not** your personal helper. When you ask a question that gets answered, it is expected that others, who might have the same question, will find their answer here without the need to ask. Right now, you basically changed a valid Q&A into a nonsense Q&A of the form `Q: Why does 1 + 1 equals 2? A: Bananas are bent, because [...]`. You deserved your question-ban.

Answer (score 7):

Yes - in the first version, the variable is not definitely assigned. In the second, it *is* definitely assigned, with the default value (0). So:

```
int a;
Console.WriteLine(a); // Error!

int a = new int();
Console.WriteLine(a); // Prints 0
```

I don't think I've ever actually deliberately written `new int()`, however. You'd usually write:

```
int a = 0;
```

as a rather more readable approach. For generic methods you could use either `default(T)` or `new T()` however, if `T` is constrained to be a non-nullable value type.

Arrays are a completely separate question, and should be asked separately.

Answer (score 3):

The latter (`int a = new int();`) assigns a value - it is basically the same as `int a = 0;` or `int a = default(int);`. This means that if it is a ***local variable*** the rules of *definite assignment are happy*. With the first (`int a;`) you can't use it until it has been assigned. For example, `Console.WriteLine(a);` would fail if you don't explicitly give `a` a value.

Note that ***fields*** (aka instance-variables and type-level variables) are inherently treated as "assigned" their default value (`0` in this case), so in the case of a field it is simply redundant code.

Answer (score 1):

The first one just declares an integer variable without initializing it's value:

```
int a;
```

Because it hasn't been initialized, you won't be able to use this it until you've assigned it a value.

The second one declares the integer variable *and* initializes it to the default value.

```
int a = new int();
```

---

To answer the second question, you can declare a two dimensional array of any type like this:

```
Button[,] buttons;
```

To initialize the array to a certain size use

```
Button[,] buttons = new Button[4, 5];
```

Although, element item in the array will be initialized to the default value for its type.